# How to find missed vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices

Sometimes I realize that I have a few vertices missed after deleting something I guess (and don't know why they keep a vertex in the limbo without connection with an edge).

The question is:

There's some way to auto detect all these missed vertices and also edges? Or the only way in by eye looking in Edit Mode?

Example:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into *Edit mode*, select all vertices (double tap <kbd>A</kbd> key), then in the viewport menu, Select *Mesh > Cleanup > Delete loose*. This will remove stray vertices

Comment: Great! Thank you :)